# Postgres alternating group query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given I have a table:

my_table

```
id INT
bool BOOLEAN
```

And some data:

```
1, true
2, true
3, false
4, true
5, true
6, false
7, false
8, false
9, true
...
```

How can I `SELECT` such that I find only the rows where there has been a change in the `bool` value between the current row's id and the previous row's id?

In this case, I would want the results to look like so:

```
1, true
3, false
4, true
6, false
9, true
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(bool) over (order by id) as prev_bool
      from mytable t
     ) t
where t.bool <> prev_bool;
```